# AWS RDS - ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES Workaround

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-rds

I'm trying to run a command of the following form against an AWS RDS cluster as the master user:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE "foo_role"
  IN SCHEMA "bar"
  GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO "foo-reader";
```

However, the `rds_superuser` role doesn't allow this:

```
ERROR:  must be member of role "foo_role"
```

AWS has a published list of what commands the `rds_superuser` role can run [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html):

```
CREATE ROLE, CREATE DB, PASSWORD VALID UNTIL INFINITY, CREATE EXTENSION, ALTER EXTENSION, DROP EXTENSION, CREATE TABLESPACE, ALTER <OBJECT> OWNER, CHECKPOINT, PG_CANCEL_BACKEND(), PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND(), SELECT PG_STAT_REPLICATION, EXECUTE PG_STAT_STATEMENTS_RESET(), OWN POSTGRES_FDW_HANDLER(), OWN POSTGRES_FDW_VALIDATOR(), OWN POSTGRES_FDW, EXECUTE PG_BUFFERCACHE_PAGES(), SELECT PG_BUFFERCACHE
```

Is it possible to run an equivalent command using just what `rds_superuser` provides, ideally without assigning the `foo_role` to the master user?

Comment: It would be a security problem if a non-superuser can give somebody privileges on somebody else's (future) tables.

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL documentation indicates that `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` can only be used by the session user, it doesn't mention that a superuser can use it for another user:

> You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

This is counterintuitive. A `superuser` role suggests that it should be able to do everything in a database.

So, it's not wrong that a superuser belongs to every user group. After all, superusers can do almost everything other users can, being `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` an exception.

```sql
GRANT role_name1 TO rds_superuser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE role_name1
  IN SCHEMA schema_name
  GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO role_name2;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html

If for whatever reason the superuser shouldn't be member of that role, then it can be removed afterwards:

```sql
REVOKE role_name1 FROM rds_superuser;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html

Alternatively, if the role is not to be assigned to the superuser, the session user may be changed when being logged in as superuser:

```sql
SET ROLE role_name1
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE role_name1
  IN SCHEMA schema_name
  GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO role_name2;
RESET ROLE
```

From the documentation, a superuser can change to any other role with `SET ROLE`:

> The specified `role_name` must be a role that the current session user
> is a member of. If the session user is a superuser, any role can be
> selected.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-role.html

So, after all, a superuser can perform `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` for any role. It's just a bit more cumbersome, having to change the session role first and resetting it later.